# Does Google Cloud Storage suffer from sequential naming like Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

Amazon S3 suffers a performance penalty if you name your files in a sequential manner (e.g. if your files are "server-.log").  Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-storage

Does this apply to Google Cloud Storage as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the **Naming** section of the [Best Practices Guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#naming):

> Avoid using sequential filenames such as timestamp-based filenames if
>   you are uploading many files in parallel. Because files with
>   sequential names are stored consecutively, they are likely to hit the
>   same backend server, meaning that throughput will be constrained. In
>   order to achieve optimal throughput, you can add the hash of the
>   sequence number as part of the filename to make it non-sequential.

Comment: **Latest documentation seems to suggest otherwise:**

_"Avoid using sequential filenames such as timestamp-based filenames if you are uploading many files in parallel. Because files with sequential names are stored consecutively, they are likely to hit the same backend server, meaning that throughput will be constrained. In order to achieve optimal throughput, you can add the hash of the sequence number as part of the filename to make it non-sequential. For more information, see Request Rate and Access Distribution Guidelines."_

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices

Comment: Other resources also suggest otherwise: https://medium.com/@duhroach/google-cloud-storage-sequential-file-names-f1ba1205c6a8

Comment: @rdlowrey thanks, the docs have since changed - updated answer

Comment: No problem, and thanks. You do a better job of updating old answers than i do 