# Proper way to name objects in mass storage service

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I wonder as one of my personal projects development goes further forward how should i organize the files ( images, videos, audio files ) uploaded by the users onto AWS's S3/GCE Cloud Storage, i'm used to see these kinds of URL below;

```
Facebook fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-9/11873531_1015...750483_5263546700711467249_n.jpg?oh=b3f06f7e...b7ebf7&oe=56392950&__gda__=1446569890_628...c7765669456
Tumblr   36.media.tumblr.com/686b47...e93fa09c2478/tumblr_nt7lnyP3ld1rqbl96o1_500.png
Twitter  pbs.twimg.com/media/CMimixsV...AcZeM.jpg
```

Does these random characters carry some kind of meaning? or they're just "UUIDs"? Is there a performance/organization issue in using, for instance this kind of URL below?

```
content.socialnetworkX.com/userY/post/customName_dinosaurs.jpg
```

EDIT: Let be clear that i'm considering millions of files.

Comment: We used S3 to store images, css and video. We always used a hierarchy that is like the one you suggest and never had any issues. In the Facebook example it appears that it is using a CDN as well, which will have an affect on the URL that is presented.

Comment: @ben_979 thanks, but how much did you had stored? I fear that problems may surge as the number of files grow.

Comment: We used versioned directories for releases, with about 6K objects per release. The document referenced by @jterrace looks valid for high usage cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For S3, see the [Performance Considerations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html#workloads-with-mix-request-types) page where it talks about object naming. Specifically, if you plan to upload objects at a high rate, you should avoid sequentially named objects, as they can be a bottleneck.

Google Cloud Storage does not have this performance bottleneck. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21167615/624900).

Comment: Another thing that bothers me, like i said, Is basically why they don't name the objects in a "pseudo-hierarchical" ( user/post/name ) way instead of "just random characters", is it just a "design choice" or is there a technical reason behind it?